# Get error message with date field in Informatica when the workflow is run

Tags: datetime, target, informatica

I am getting the following error when I try to link a date field from Source Qualifier to Target table in Informatica:
ERROR   7/19/2019 9:05:26 AM    node01_dev  WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8229    Database errors occurred: 
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]Timestamp parameters with zero scale must have a precision of 13, 16, or 19.  Parameter number: 1, precision: 12.
FnName: Execute -- [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Function sequence error

I have done the same thing (used datetime for a target) with another workflow and it ran successfully.

I have done a search on the internet with this error message but none of the solutions from my search resolved the problem.

The target table SA_Cases needs to have the data insert into it.  Right now, the Monitor shows that all of the rows are rejected.

The source is a table in Oracle.  The target is a table in Microsoft SQL Server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uvjZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCCX5.png)

Here is the mapping that works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuV9j.png)

Comment: is the session timestamp precision the same between the problematic session and the known good one? are the source definitions set to use the same odbc drivers?  we've had issues before with oracle timestamps not having high enough precision when an older odbc driver was used.

Comment: You are correct that this has to do with the Oracle timestamps not having enough high precision.  I do not know how to resolve this issue.  The session timestamp precision is exactly the same in the session that works and the problematic session.

Comment: I think this has to be that the precision in the source>date field has a different precision than the target>date field.  The source>date field is from Oracle with with a date type of "date" whereas the target>date field is from MIcrosoft SQL with date type as "datetime".

Comment: can you use the mapping debugger to verify the precision of the dates coming out of oracle source tables between good and bad mappings are the same? im thinking the drivers are not the same when the sources were created, which can cause you to not have the msec precision. this is a known issue between the datadirect versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SA_Cases table, which is the Target table, has fields with spaces.  I replaced the spaces with underscores and it works.  The problem was the spaces in the field names.